# ¿cambiar icono de un jlabel en java con una tecla (cualquiera),?

Tags: java

Tengo un código de una aplicación que muestra una secuencia de imágenes con un `switch` que cambian cada ciertos segundos. Esto lo hice con un `timer` pero necesito que cuando oprima una tecla, cambie a la siguiente imagen que corresponde a dicha secuencia.

Cómo puedo lograr esto?

```
public class RM_secuenciaImagenes {
static int contador = 0; 

public void secuenciaImagen(){
    int Velocidad = 3;
    Timer timer;
    TimerTask Tarea;

    int velmil = Velocidad*1000;

    RM_PruebaEnsayo ensayo = new RM_PruebaEnsayo();
    ensayo.setVisible(true);

    Tarea = new TimerTask(){
        @Override

        public void run() {       
            Icon Imagenes;

            switch(contador){
                case 0 : 
                    contador =1;
                    // System.out.println("");
                    Imagenes = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Imagenes/Estimulo_4.png"));                       
                    ensayo.sec_La.setIcon(Imagenes);
                    break;
                case 1: 
                    contador = 2;
                    // System.out.println("");
                    Imagenes = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Imagenes/Estimulo_1.png"));                       
                    ensayo.sec_La.setIcon(Imagenes);
                    break;
                case 2: 
                    contador = 3;
                    // System.out.println("");
                    Imagenes = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Imagenes/Estimulo_2.png"));                       
                    ensayo.sec_La.setIcon(Imagenes);
                    break;
                case 3: 
                    contador = 0;
                    // System.out.println("");
                    Imagenes = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Imagenes/Estimulo_3.png"));                       
                    ensayo.sec_La.setIcon(Imagenes);
                    break;                              
                }
            }
        };
        timer = new Timer();   
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(Tarea, 2000, velmil);      
    }

    private static void stop() {
```

Comment: podrias agregar tu codigo para ver como funciona

Comment: ese es el código que llevo hasta ahora agradecería su ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se debe agregar un evento sobre el jframe o sobre la vista donde aparece la imagen, en el codigo solo aparece el que corre el contador pero para poder tener acceso a las pulsaciones del teclado se debe situar el event sobre la vista, un ejemplo en etiqueta de como usar el event es el siguiente.

```
   <Form version="1.5" maxVersion="1.9"  type="org.netbeans.modules.form.forminfo.JFrameFormInfo">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="defaultCloseOperation" type="int" value="3"/>
        <Property name="extendedState" type="int" value="6"/>
        <Property name="undecorated" type="boolean" value="true"/>
    </Properties>
    <SyntheticProperties>
        <SyntheticProperty name="formSizePolicy" type="int" value="1"/>
         <SyntheticProperty name="generateCenter" type="boolean" value="false"/>
  </SyntheticProperties>
  <Events>
    <EventHandler event="mouseClicked" listener="java.awt.event.MouseListener" parameters="java.awt.event.MouseEvent" handler="formMouseClicked"/>
    <EventHandler event="mousePressed" listener="java.awt.event.MouseListener" parameters="java.awt.event.MouseEvent" handler="formMousePressed"/>
    <EventHandler event="mouseReleased" listener="java.awt.event.MouseListener" parameters="java.awt.event.MouseEvent" handler="formMouseReleased"/>
    <EventHandler event="keyPressed" listener="java.awt.event.KeyListener" parameters="java.awt.event.KeyEvent" handler="formKeyPressed"/>
  </Events>
  </Form>
```

En el codigo se puede ver que se esta agregando 4 tipos diferentes de eventos sobre el frame, los cuales son

- Mouseclicked
- MousePressed
- MouseReleased
- KeyPressed

El que se necesita utilizar es el KeyPressed, este evento captura cada pulsacion que se realiza en el teclado cuando se encuentra situado en la vista, el codigo que acompaña esta vista es la del archivo java que acompaña el formulario en donde se debe crear un metodo como el siguiente:

```
 private void formKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
        char dato = evt.getKeyChar();
       } 
    }//GEN-LAST:event_formKeyPressed
```

Este metodo captura la pulsacion generada por el evento de la vista y obtiene el dato de tipo char, ya con esto se obtiene la pulsacion ahora lo que solo queda es modificar su metodo de tiempo y que utlice el contador cada vez que algo pase por el metodo **formKeyPressed**

La clase que tienes debe quedar de la siguiente manera

```
    import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

/**
 *
 * @author jorgelp
 */
public class CambioImagen {


    private int contador = 0; 
        RM_PruebaEnsayo ensayo = new RM_PruebaEnsayo();
        ensayo.setVisible(true);

    public  void cambiar(){
                Icon Imagenes;

                this.validarContador();

                switch(contador){
                    case 0 : 
                        // System.out.println("");
                        Imagenes = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Imagenes/Estimulo_4.png"));                       
                        ensayo.sec_La.setIcon(Imagenes);
                        break;
                    case 1: 
                        // System.out.println("");
                        Imagenes = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Imagenes/Estimulo_1.png"));                       
                        ensayo.sec_La.setIcon(Imagenes);
                        break;
                    case 2: 
                        // System.out.println("");
                        Imagenes = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Imagenes/Estimulo_2.png"));                       
                        ensayo.sec_La.setIcon(Imagenes);
                        break;
                    case 3: 
                        // System.out.println("");
                        Imagenes = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Imagenes/Estimulo_3.png"));                       
                        ensayo.sec_La.setIcon(Imagenes);
                        break;                              
                    }
     }


    public void validarContador(){
        this.contador++;

        if(contador> 3){
            this.contador = 0;
        }

    }

   }
```

Y en el jframe agregas el evento de **formKeyPressed** que llame al metodo **CambioImagen.cambiar()**

Comment: eso fue mas complejo de lo que esperaba muchas gracias, este código no se como implementarlo disculpa mi ignorancia, como debería aplicarlo

Comment: Cuando tu creas un JLabel este debe estar dentro de un JFRAME si es una aplicacion de escritorio, en caso de ser un una plataforma web lo que haces es utilizar programacion orientada a eventos  en donde pones que crearas un evento de tipo formKeyPressed entro del constructor de la clase, investiga mas sobre events java hay puedes tener mas claro como implementarlo, es que con el codigo que das no muestras nada del jlabel.

Comment: yo tengo el jlabel dentro de un JFrame, pero el codigo que te muestro es de una clase que ejecuta en dicho jframe por eso hago la instancia de el jframe y en esta clase utlizo el jlabel.

Comment: claro pero la accion del caracter usted la envia desde el jframe no desde la instancia de la clase que envia la imagen, entonces el evento se pone desde el jframe y la clase que tienes se debe modificar, quitas primero la logica del timer, en el metodo run  aumentas el contador en 1 y ya con eso debes poder funcionar adjunto la clase modificada

Comment: Edite la respuesta ya con eso deberias poder resolver la pregunta

Comment: muchas gracias, eres un proo regalame un ejemplo en código con las modificaciones que me dijiste si por fa, lo implementare te diré como me fue

Comment: Pues el que te adjunte es como puede quedar la clase que cambia la imagen para poder poner el event listering en la vista necesito el codigo de la vista

Comment: es que la secuencia ya esta establecida por el contador y el timer pero quiero que si ya se reacciono a esa imagen se pase a la que sigue en la secuencia. seguirá siendo automática pero también se cambiara al momento que ya se reacciono.

Comment: te puedo enviar el archivo y lo ves mejor?

Comment: Es lo mismo, entonces deja el timmer que tienes, haces un metodo aparte para que llame al mismo metodo del timmer y pones el event listering en la clase, para poder solucionar mas necesito mas informacion pero con lo que publicaste veo que ya esta resuelta la pregunta que escribiste ya lo que deseas es otra pregunta, por favor califica esta y le damos continuidad al event en la vista.

Comment: regalame tu correo y le envio el archivo le parece

Comment: señor jorge no se como implementar el método que usted me dice no como hacerlo me ayuda.