# ¿Cómo obtengo el tiempo de secuencia de imágenes establecidas con timer?

Tags: java

Tengo el código de un programa, consiste en una secuencia de imágenes dentro de un `switch` con un `timer`, necesito medir el tiempo de reacción de un usuario ante esas imágenes. Desde que apareció la imagen hasta la reacción, asignándole una tecla a cada imagen, si oprime la tecla que no es, debe salir un mensaje de error que debería hacer.

```
public class RM_secuenciaImagenes {
    static int contador = 0; 

    public void secuenciaImagen(){
      int Velocidad = 3;
            Timer timer;
            TimerTask Tarea;


               int velmil = Velocidad*1000;

               RM_PruebaEnsayo ensayo = new RM_PruebaEnsayo();
               ensayo.setVisible(true);

               Tarea = new TimerTask(){     
                    @Override

                 public void run() {

                     Icon Imagenes;

                     switch(contador){
                         case 0 : 
                           contador =1;
                           // System.out.println("");
                              Imagenes = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Imagenes/Estimulo_4.png"));                       
                              ensayo.sec_La.setIcon(Imagenes);
                             break;
                              case 1: 
                               contador = 2;
                            // System.out.println("");
                              Imagenes = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Imagenes/Estimulo_1.png"));                       
                              ensayo.sec_La.setIcon(Imagenes);
                             break;
                              case 2: 
                           contador = 3;
                            // System.out.println("");
                              Imagenes = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Imagenes/Estimulo_2.png"));                       
                              ensayo.sec_La.setIcon(Imagenes);
                             break;
                               case 3: 
                           contador = 0;
                            // System.out.println("");
                              Imagenes = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Imagenes/Estimulo_3.png"));                       
                              ensayo.sec_La.setIcon(Imagenes);
                             break;    


                     }
                 }



               };

               timer = new Timer();

               timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(Tarea, 2000, velmil);      
}
    private static void stop() {   

    }
```

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿cambiar icono de un jlabel en java con una tecla (cualquiera),?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/289205/cambiar-icono-de-un-jlabel-en-java-con-una-tecla-cualquiera)

Comment: @JorgeReinaldoLinaresPineda se parece, pero acá pregunta como tomar el tiempo entre cuando se muestra y cuando oprimes una tecla

Comment: exacto me podrias ayudar con esto por fa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una forma algo viejita pero simple es usar `System.nanoTime` para obtener el tiempo con presición en dos momentos determinados y hacer la resta para obtener el delta.

```
long momentoDeInicio = System.nanoTime();
// aquí ejecuta tu código
long momentoDeTermino = System.nanoTime();

long tiempo = (endTime - startTime);  //está en nanosegundos, así que si lo prefieres divide entre 1000000 para obtenerlo en milisegundos.
```

Ahora entre las consideraciones de swing que tal vez quieras tomar en cuenta está la de poner el pintado en el hilo de gráficos y establecer `momentoDeInicio` allí para asegurarte que realmente sea en el momento en que se pinta.

Esto puede hacerlo mediante la clase de utiulidades de Swing y llamando el repintado mediante el método `SwingUtilities.InvokeLater`.

Comment: como aplicarlo a mi proyecto me enseñarias por fa

Comment: con el poco código que pusiste me es imposible. Por este motivo siempre trata de poner un [mcve]

Comment: eso es lo que tengo hasta ahora no se como avansar un